# Loading second div behind first div. then hiding first div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Current Implementation:

1. two divs at same place, div1 display:block, div2 display:none
2. on tab click, Jquery hides one in 2000ms and shows other div.

Problem:
I dont want user to feel like 2nd div loaded after tab clicked.
I want user to feel that second div was there when first div disapeared.

Current Code:

```
div1.hide('fade', 2000, function() {
    div2.show();
});
```

I need something like:

```
div2.show(); //behind div1
div1.hide('fade', 2000);
```

but this shows both `divs` on screen for 2 seconds which I dont want to.

Please help.

Comment: The CSS style display:none removes the element - what you want is visibility: hidden.  The difference between visibility and display on an element is that visibility keeps the object in it's physical space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your support sir, I have aceived it by using the comments of everyone. Have a look bro http://jsfiddle.net/bhailogee/CA7Bu/3 thanks

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(".tab1").on("click",function(){
        prepare($(".div2"),$(".div1"));
        $(".div1").hide('slide', 2000,function(){
            clean($(".div2"),$(".div1"));
            $(".div2").show();
        });                
    })
    $(".tab2").on("click",function(){
        prepare($(".div1"),$(".div2"));
         $(".div2").hide('slide', 2000,function(){
            clean($(".div1"),$(".div2"));
            $(".div1").show();
         });
    })

    function prepare(showdiv,hidediv){    
    showdiv.css('position','absolute');
    hidediv.css('position','absolute');
    showdiv.css('z-index','1');
    hidediv.css('z-index','2');
    showdiv.css('display','block');
    hidediv.css('display','block');
}

function clean(showdiv,hidediv){
    showdiv.css('z-index', '');
    hidediv.css('z-index', '');
}
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to code something like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
   $(".tab2").on("click",function(){
      $(".div2").stop(true,true).slideUp(function(){
          $(".div1").stop(true,true).slideDown();
       });

   })
  $(".tab1").on("click",function(){
      $(".div1").stop(true,true).slideUp(function(){
        $(".div2").stop(true,true).slideDown();
        });
     })
 });
```

Put your class or id name on which you want to click instead of `.tab`

Here is demo of full tab pane: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jkkheni/xbjEA/5/)

Comment: I think this is not what I am looking for... It stops the animation when it is clicked on tab twice. have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/bhailogee/CA7Bu/2/. It shows second div after first div disappears. I need to show it like 2nd div already there. we just removed first div by sliding it.

Comment: thank you for your support sir, I have aceived it by using the comments of everyone. Have a look bro http://jsfiddle.net/bhailogee/CA7Bu/3/ thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stop()` to block the queueing of animations, like so:

```
$('#click').click(function() {
    $("#div1").stop().fadeTo(2000, 0);
    $("#div2").stop().fadeTo(2000, 1);
});
```

Here's a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/remus/xbjEA/)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for sounds like 2 div's behind each other, using `z-index`. You just put them in the same place, give the one in the back a lower z-index and then `fadeOut` the top one. This way the second one will actually be there already and you don't need the `show()` or `fadeIn()`. Example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LelpI)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little bit sexier way than loading the second div later. stack the divs, then fade out the top one and hide it with the animation callback when it's done. (or, use `fadeOut` as BenMann suggests for the same result.)

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YMQgA/)

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='divFront'>some content on top, click for other content</div>
    <div id='divBack'><br />some other content underneath</div>
</div>
$('#divFront').click(function(){
    $('#divFront').animate({"opacity":"0"}, 2000, "swing", function(){
      $('#divFront').hide();
    });
});
```